# How to make vim-css-color colorize a markdown buffer?

Tags: plugin-csscolor

I'm using [vim-css-color](https://github.com/ap/vim-css-color) to highlight the color code like #800080 with the corresponding background.

It does it well for Python code:

[image]

But I would like to have the "same" for markdown document.

What should I do to ensure that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [vim-markdown](https://github.com/preservim/vim-markdown) create a `~/.vim/after/syntax/markdown.vim` with the following content:

```
if match(&runtimepath, 'vim-css-color') != -1
  call css_color#init('hex', 'none', 'mkdListItemLine,mkdNonListItemBlock')
endif
```

The first test `match(&runtimepath, 'vim-css-color') != -1` verifies that the [vim-css-color](https://github.com/ap/vim-css-color) plugin is installed and running.

The second line activate the detection of color codes within the highlighting groups:

- `mkdListItemLine`
- `mkdNonListItemBlock`

Remark: If you miss some part of the document you can use the following command:

```
echo synIDattr(synID(line("."),col("."),1),"name")`
```

to detect the highlighting group to which they are corresponding and add it to the list.

Comment: How does it solve the problem? Why `after/syntax/markdown.vim` and not another file? Where is the documentation for that? Why did you post this here instead of sending a PR to the plugin's maintainer?

Comment: I have enriched my answer. The plugin has no documentation in GitHub nor in Vim :-| I can't pretend writing one from scratch and I have a doubt that if I do it will be accepted.

Comment: You could submit your `syntax/markdown.vim`.

Comment: FYI [Feature Request: Markdown Copy](https://github.com/ap/vim-css-color/issues/141)

Comment: Thanks @Friedrich. I'll comment the issue and redirect to my question :-)

Comment: Tried to reproduce and noticed you need [preservim/vim-markdown](https://github.com/preservim/vim-markdown) installed for this to work. The default (tpope) markdown syntax has different highlight groups.

Comment: @Friedrich, thanks for comment. I have updated the solution. When I got some time I'll update the solution for the default markdown syntax.